# Enabling HTTPS in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fuelphp, aws-certificate-manager

I am running a web application is AWS. I have a load balanced environment set up in Elastic Beanstalk and i have attached a certificate to that for HTTPS.

When i access the homepage URL, HTTPS works absolutely fine. The issue i have is when i add something to the URL such as /login then HTTPS just refuses to work and only HTTP will work.

It seems that it worked fine when it was using the sample application. However when i have uploaded my files to the environment it has the issue.

I am running a FuelPHP application. Does anyone know a fix for this, is it to do with my htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with a similar issue, it was Fuel PHP which was the issue. There is a setting under fuel/app/config/config.php to allow HTTP requests. Uncomment the following line:

```
'allow_x_headers' => true,
```